# $.post () - Dúvida

Tags: jquery, post

Estou com um problema:

Eu já consegui lendo e seguindo a documentação do facebook, usar seus métodos e pegar algumas infos que eles disponibilizam. Agora que eu consegui isso, preciso enviar por $.post() uma dessas infos (userID).

Não estou conseguindo na documentação do jQuery entender o uso deste método. Alguém poderia me ajudar, já tô a dois dias nesse problema e sei que é pouco tempo, mas como disse, não sou habilidoso em javascript ou nessas linguagens client side.

Esse é um trecho do método onde eu botei para exibir dentro de uma div o resultado da variável uid que recebe userID do próprio face:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){

        if (response.status === 'connected'){
            $('#logar').hide();
            $('#status').append('<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="logout()" id="logout"></a>');

            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            $('#status').html('Seu userID é '+uid+'');              
        } 

    });
```

Isso é o que estou fazendo para enviar pelo $.post(), dizendo que o conteúdo da div é a info que estou passando e enviando após um evento click:

```
(function facebook(){ 
      $("button").click(function(){
        $.post("url-da-minha-escolha", $("#status"), function(data){
            alert(data);
        } )
    }); 
});
```

Enfim, já tentei outras alternativas também .... essa no caso foi minha última tentativa. Quem puder me ajudar ou dar dica ou fornecer um material mais explicativo já agradeço.

Comment: Coloque mais informação a respeito do erro. Dá algum erro? Se sim, coloque o erro que está dando. A sua variável "data" vem com algum valor?

Comment: @AndréLuisMarmo, não dá erro ... do jeito que está ele retorna todo o html da página dentro do data, quando por exemplo tento algo como data.nome caso eu tenha passado as variáveis por parametro dentro da função post, ele retorna undefined.
Todos os exemplos disponíveis são simples assim, inclusive já tentei enviar para teste as variáveis por dentro da função .post ex:  {nome: "nome", ... } e mesmo assim  o retorno do data e continua vindo todo o conteúdo do html ... ex: <html><body> etc ... dentro da variável.

Comment: Se o retorno é o html, é porque esta url que está sendo dado o post não retorna um json por exemplo que você possa converter e assim conseguir um "data.nome". Tem que saber qual o comportamento da url que você está realizando o post. Talvez tenha que dar o post mas e a navegação continuar na url de destino e se for assim você não poderá usar o post do jquery.

Comment: Consegui resolver meu problema, muito obrigado a quem tentou ajudar!
A solução que encontrei foi usar o próprio método post porém na página da solicitação da requisição eu usei recursos do form do coldfusion e estou printando na tela o valor da variável desejada. Ahh também transformei a variável em global, assim dentro do próprio método do post eu leio o valor que vem do facebook ;)

Comment: Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos